# How to transform Flutter web app into a PWA?

Tags: flutter, dart, progressive-web-apps

I am making a new Web application with Flutter web.
I want to add service workers to my app in order to make it a PWA.

What I need to use to achieve my goal ?

I have tried to do it with dart packages (service_worker or pwa), but they are deprecated for Dart 2.

Comment: Why not just use the flutter mobile version of the app for mobile? Isn't that kind of the point of flutter web in the first place? This seems like an unnecessarily complex situation that could be avoided.

Comment: Hello,
I wanted my app to be avaible offline on navigator (PC or mobile).
Because a mobile app won't be avaible on your navigator :'(

Answer (score 3):

Since a service worker is just javascript code you can write one in plain javascript (e.g. in a `sw.js` file), bundle it with your flutter web app and then register the service worker from the `index.html` file like this ([source](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/registration)):

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently need to switch to **Flutter Channel Dev** **(at Feb 17th 2020, current Dev version 1.15.3)**

For existing projects, use the terminal to hit the command:

`flutter create .`

For new projects, you would have a 2 files: **`manifest.json`** and **`index.html`** inside your **web** folder.

While checking **`index.html`** you would notice the following script:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
     navigator.serviceWorker.register('/flutter_service_worker.js');
  });
}
```

If the script is not there, added inside **`<body></body>`**

This script creates the **PWA** support for you and be able to "install" the app on a device (this also includes **MacOS**)

Follow this **[GUIDE](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/migrate-to-progressive-web-apps/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)** to complete your **PWA** functionalities.